# android array index exception

Tags: android, arrays

i have an activity that include imageview and gridview.the rules is when i click selected image on gridview,it will be previewed by imageview.then,the imageview can be clicked and it will be showed on dialog.the problem is when i clicked the imageview, the image is not match with selected image in gridview.here my code.

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {

ImageView imgviewThumb, imgviewPreviewDialog;
public int[] imageResto = {
        R.drawable.img1,
        R.drawable.img2,
        R.drawable.img3,
        R.drawable.img4,
        R.drawable.img5,
        R.drawable.img1,
        R.drawable.img2,
        R.drawable.img3,
        R.drawable.img4
};
int position ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

    imgviewThumb = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview_preview);
    imgviewThumb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(GalleryActivity.this);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_previewimage);
            imgviewPreviewDialog = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgview_preview_dialog);
            imgviewPreviewDialog.setImageResource(imageResto[position]);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    GridView gView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_View);

    //Instantiating ImageAdapter class
    gView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    /*showing full image on clicking the thumbnail
     * create a new class named FullImage.java 
     */
    gView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            imgviewThumb.setImageResource(imageResto[position]);
        }
    });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(140, 140));
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        return imageView;
    }

    private Context mContext;

    // images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
             R.drawable.thumb1_e,
             R.drawable.thumb2,
             R.drawable.thumb3,
             R.drawable.thumb4,
             R.drawable.thumb5,
             R.drawable.thumb1,
             R.drawable.thumb2,
             R.drawable.thumb3,
             R.drawable.thumb4
    };
}
}
```

please correct me.thanks for advance.

Comment: please Post your logcat thanks!

Comment: since you have an Array, why not extending ArrayAdapter instead of BaseAdapter?

Comment: @Remdroid the logcat shows that there are java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9.thanks for suggest :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
}
```

To this:

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
}
```

Comment: still not working.i mean when dialog showed,it will preview a selected image on grid.but thanks your suggests :-)

Comment: what exactly is the problem? does it throw any exception?

Comment: i mean the image is not show in dialog, when i run and build project there is no error :-(

Comment: does it return a valid array index value when you click an item from list?

Answer (score 0):

i think you using  both different array so its possible mismatch ,

```
public int[] imageResto = {
        R.drawable.img1,
        R.drawable.img2,
        R.drawable.img3,
        R.drawable.img4,
        R.drawable.img5,
        R.drawable.img1,
        R.drawable.img2,
        R.drawable.img3,
        R.drawable.img4
};

  // images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
             R.drawable.thumb1_e,
             R.drawable.thumb2,
             R.drawable.thumb3,
             R.drawable.thumb4,
             R.drawable.thumb5,
             R.drawable.thumb1,
             R.drawable.thumb2,
             R.drawable.thumb3,
             R.drawable.thumb4
    };
```

And put valid Image Array
position is here getting is right 0 to length of Array in apter so its write position get here

```
 gView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            imgviewThumb.setImageResource(validImageArray[position]);
        }
    });
```

or You can do like this change in getView

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(140, 140));
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(imageResto[position]);

        return imageView;
    }
```

Comment: i guess the issue is on imgviewPreviewDialog.setImageResource(imageResto[positions]).because there is no problem in setOnItemClick,the image has already match with selected item on grid.i mean when i click that imageview,dialog will display the image :-)

Comment: the logcat shows that there is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9